# SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql-server-2014

Can anyone please explain if SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2013(for SQL 2014) is licensed or free? Do we need to purchase additional license for this or it can be used  with SQL 2014 license?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

there is a version free :

```
sql server express
```

and another to buy with extended options :

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server/purchasing.aspx

but in the most cases the express version contain the most you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ilyas, just wanted to ensure if there's a need to purchase a separate license for SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2013(Used to develop SSIS packages) if I already have a license of SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition?

Comment: @MohammadFarooque: no need to purchase in this case